# Adding a custom directive to ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

[image]

Can i add a custom directive to the input cell of the ng-grid..Can someone help me , i searched it but was unable to find Thanks for any help

Here is reference of ng-grid

```
https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [custom editable cell templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Templating) like:

```
{
    field: 'name',
    cellClass: 'nameCell',
    headerClass: 'nameHeader',
    editableCellTemplate: '<div your-custom-directive>' +
    '<form name="inputForm">' +
    '<input type="number" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD">' +
    '</form>' +
    '</div>'
}
```